# SQL in databricks gives either cartesian warning or just no result - what's wrong with my query?

Tags: sql, join, databricks

I have given an excel sheet (which is exported from an application) with the following columns:

```
PR ID   | Grid ID | Lot#/Serial# | Code/Part# | Product Family Name | Lot Description | Manufacturing Location | Quantity/Unit | Recommendation | Dispo Date | Dispo Comment |
1156457 | 2257    | aaaaaaaaaaaaa| 307782     | bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb | ccccccccccccccc | dddddddddddddddddddddd | 1 bottle      |  eeeeeeeeeeeee | 04.01.2017 | adfasdf       |
```

All this data is stored in databricks as well and I need to retrieve / query the same data for automation purposes (the app doesn't offer this feature). So the purposed outcome are the columns with the same data as given in excel.

I manage to get the first 4 columns (pr id, grid id, lot/serial, and code/part) with this code:

```
SELECT
  f1.pr_id,
  f1.grid_id,
  f1.grid_field_value AS LotSerial,
  f2.grid_field_value AS CodePart
FROM
  GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f1,
  GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f2
WHERE
  f1.pr_id = f2.pr_id
  AND f1.seq_no=f2.seq_no
  AND f1.grid_id = f2.grid_id
  AND f1.grid_field_nm = 'Lot#/Serial#'
  AND f2.grid_field_nm = 'Code/Part#'
  AND f2.grid_nm = "Lot Info. Grid"
```

Whatever I try I get either a cartesian warning / error or just no results (meaning in databrick just an 'OK'). The code above was given as example and following the logic behind it my latest attempt is the code below but that gives me just an 'OK', so no results.

```
SELECT
  f1.pr_id,
  f1.grid_id,
  f1.grid_field_value AS LotSerial,
  f2.grid_field_value AS CodePart,
  f2.grid_field_value AS ProductFamilyName
FROM
  GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f1
  JOIN GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f2 ON f1.pr_id = f2.pr_id
WHERE
  f1.grid_field_nm = 'Lot#/Serial#'
  AND f2.grid_field_nm = 'Code/Part#'
  AND f2.grid_field_nm = 'Product Family Name'
  AND f2.grid_nm = "Lot Info. Grid"
```

I'm running out of ideas. What part of SQL do I not understand?

Comment: If you are getting no results, then your filter conditions are not matching any rows.  You need to investigate why this is happening.

Comment: ok, would you be so kind and give another hint as just "wrong filter" and downgrading the question?

Comment: . . I don't downvote, so the downvote is someone else.  The issue is that your `where` conditions or `on` conditions simply do not match data.

Comment: Comment out your WHERE clause and see if that returns any data; if it doesn't then there is an issue with your join. Assuming it does return data, then add back each statement in your WHERE clause one by one until you find the one that is causing the problem (because when you add it back in your query stops returning any data)

Comment: If after commenting the where caluse you wtill didn't get any result try to focus on join condition. You may see there are some rows in both tables with the same `pr_id` but make sure the data type is the same and if that's a string there is no whitespace before and after. If these are ok then in the next step you could also check the value encoding, the excel files are in ANSI mode which mostly we expect o have UTF-8 values in input files.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the reason for whom that downvote this question, I think this is a normal question with a good level of details. I will upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted out, it was a question of proper connecting the dots. Since it turned out to be some kind of copy/pasting I'm pretty sure there would be a better way to write the query (just imagine having 100+ tables...).

```
%sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  (
    SELECT --DISTINCT -- 77.629 when using DISTINCT 
      f1.pr_id,
      f1.grid_id,
      f1.grid_field_value AS LotSerial,
      f2.grid_field_value AS CodePart,
      f3.grid_field_value AS ProductFamilyName,
      f4.grid_field_value AS LotDescription,
      f5.grid_field_value AS ManufacturingLocation,
      f6.grid_field_value AS QuantityUnitMeasure,
      f7.grid_field_value AS RecommendedLotDisposition,
      f8.grid_field_value AS DispositionDate,
      f9.grid_field_value AS DispositionComment,
      f10.grid_field_value AS RecommendedBy
    FROM
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f1,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f2,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f3,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f4,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f5,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f6,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f7,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f8,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f9,
      GRID_DATA_DETAIL_TRKW_GLBL f10
    WHERE
      f1.pr_id = f2.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f3.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f4.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f5.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f6.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f7.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f8.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f9.pr_id
      AND f1.pr_id = f10.pr_id

      AND f2.pr_id = f3.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f4.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f5.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f6.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f7.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f8.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f9.pr_id
      AND f2.pr_id = f10.pr_id

      AND f1.seq_no = f2.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f3.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f4.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f5.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f6.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f7.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f8.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f9.seq_no
      AND f1.seq_no = f10.seq_no

      AND f2.seq_no = f3.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f4.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f5.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f6.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f7.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f8.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f9.seq_no
      AND f2.seq_no = f10.seq_no

      AND f1.grid_id = f2.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f3.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f4.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f5.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f6.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f7.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f8.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f9.grid_id
      AND f1.grid_id = f10.grid_id

      AND f2.grid_id = f3.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f4.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f5.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f6.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f7.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f8.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f9.grid_id
      AND f2.grid_id = f10.grid_id

      AND f1.grid_field_nm = 'Lot#/Serial#'
      AND f2.grid_field_nm = 'Code/Part#'
      AND f3.grid_field_nm = 'Product Family Name'
      AND f4.grid_field_nm = 'Lot Description'
      AND f5.grid_field_nm = 'Manufacturing Location'
      AND f6.grid_field_nm = 'Quantity/Unit of Measure'
      AND f7.grid_field_nm = 'Recommended Lot Disposition'
      AND f8.grid_field_nm = 'Disposition Date'
      AND f9.grid_field_nm = 'Disposition Comment'
      AND f10.grid_field_nm = 'Recommended By'

      AND f2.grid_nm = "Lot Info. Grid" -- 77.730 rows
      --AND f3.grid_nm = "Lot Info. Grid" -- no difference in result/rows when adding f3.grid
      --AND "Lot Info. Grid" IN (f2.grid_nm, f3.grid_nm)
  ) AS result
```

The given excel sheet contains 10.487 rows whereas I get 77.730 rows.
I think the 10k results comes from having grid_id = 2257.
How can I add an additional filter here?

I tried:

```
%sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  result
CASE
  grid_id = 2257 (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          --DISTINCT -- 77.629 when using DISTINCT
```

So please let me know if there is any error in my logic!!

Comment: Hi - you should be using ANSI SQL JOIN syntax as it is much easier to write (correctly) and understand. The Oracle syntax that you've used has been considered outdated for years (decades!)